# .NET MVC 4 Kendo UI Grid and file upload

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

Is there a possibility to do smoething like this:

1. I have a window with KendoGrid. DataSource is binded to model which contains a list of AttachmentDetails:
   FileName, Content, Description, etc.
2. I have a button on top of the form to "Save" the modified/added/deleted list to database.
3. I have a button to "Add" new Attachement. This opens a new window via javascript open.window.
4. On that window I have a form with fields for model AttachmentDetails with input type "file" to get the Contents.
5. When I click "Save" on that new window It should close itself, and add new item to Grid on the parent window.

How can I do this kind of usabillity with Kendo?
Should I use Session to store the list with Content?

Answer (score 1):

So you want when you are done uploading the file to refresh the Grid and display that new records? If that's the case you should  use the [dataSource.read()](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#read) method to refresh the Grid when the success callback of the uploading is called.